# Using jquery getScript in a rails 3 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So after following a railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax) about loading records through ajax when someone clicks a link, I have the following javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#dash_container th a").live("click", function() {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```

This works perfectly.

However, in my template file, I'm trying to work with Pusher to achive something similar:

```
  var pusher = new Pusher('MYID');
  var channel = pusher.subscribe('newposts');

  channel.bind(<%= @push_ch %>, function(data) {
        $.getScript(this.href);
        return false;
  });
```

This used to work just fine - but I think I've included a javascript file that has broken it... When the pusher channel is now supposed to reload the set of records, I get the following type of error in my browser log:

GET Undefined?_ 1312905840215 404

clearly, its looking for something thats not there, rather than refreshing the records. This makes me think I'm improperly using the (this.href) call, as its trying to load something else.

Also, I have the following in my index.js.erb - which is what should be refreshed:

```
$("#dash_container").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("dashboard")) %>");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this was easy enough...

```
  channel.bind(<%= @push_ch %>, function(data) {
        $.getScript("#dash_container");
        return false;
  });
```